# Where's my status bar on the S8?

Tags: samsung

I've just upgraded to a Samsung S8, and the status bar at the top keeps disappearing! How do I get it to always be displayed when I'm on the home screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is embarrassing. When I first got my phone, google restored my previous desktop wallpaper, which is white at the top (it's a cloudy day photo).

On the S8, the status bar has no background, so I had white icons on the white wallpaper. This seems a little silly to me!

Comment: Note if I reset the wallpaper back to the same picture, it's clever enough to change the icon colours. So it's just an initial restore issue.